# Как сделать плавную прокрутку страницы?

Tags: jquery

Как делается плавная прокрутка страницы на сайте?
Мы скроллим страницу, а она прокручивается не рывками, а плавно, как [тут](http://nemiroff.vodka).
Какие плагины для этого есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел для этих целей плагин [jQuery.scrollSpeed](https://github.com/nathco/jQuery.scrollSpeed)

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

Для начала нужно будет прикрепить библиотеку JQuery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Затем прикрепить сам JQuery плагин, который и отвечает за плавную прокрутку, и вместе с ним же идут отдельные правила CSS которые изменяют саму полосу прокрутки на сайте.

```
 <script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
```

Также нужно добавить одно правило в стили CSS.

**CSS**

```
html, body{
height: 100%;
}
```

Это нужно для того, чтобы дать понять плагину, что ширина страницы растянута и является 100% в высоту. Если не добавить - прокрутка работать не будет.

**Скрипт**

После того как Вы всё добавили, что представлено выше, нужно включить сам скрипт. Нужно добавить желательно перед закрывающем тегом  в конце кода сайта:

```
<script>
(function($){
$(window).load(function(){

$("body").mCustomScrollbar({
theme:"dark-thin"
});

});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```